# Pyspark - advanced aggregation of monthly data

Tags: pyspark

I have a table of the following format.

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Customer       |     Month        |         Sales    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A          |         3        |         40       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A          |         2        |         50       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          B          |         1        |         20       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I need it in the format as below

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Customer       |     Month 1      |        Month 2   |         Month 3  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A          |         0        |         50       |         40       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          B          |         20       |          0       |          0       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Can you please help me out to solve this problem in PySpark?

Comment: Have you tried doing joins with spark dataframes? ([link](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-dataframe-join/)) It would do either a self join or left join onto a df of unique customers.

Comment: how many distinct values will the `Month` column in your original DF will have , i am assuming if it's YYYY-MM  or MM .

Comment: @Adithya Vikram I have 12 distinct values.

Comment: @ will cass I did try join, but hit a roadblock and could not go further. I think I am on the verge of solving it now, using pivots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help , i am assumming you are using SUM to aggregate vales from the originical DF

```
>>> df.show()
+--------+-----+-----+
|Customer|Month|Sales|
+--------+-----+-----+
|       A|    3|   40|
|       A|    2|   50|
|       B|    1|   20|
+--------+-----+-----+

>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> df2=(df.withColumn('COLUMN_LABELS',F.concat(F.lit('Month '),F.col('Month')))
.groupby('Customer')
.pivot('COLUMN_LABELS')
.agg(F.sum('Sales'))
.fillna(0))

>>> df2.show()
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|Customer|Month 1|Month 2|Month 3|
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|       A|      0|     50|     40|
|       B|     20|      0|      0|
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much Aditya, I was researching the use of pivots priorly. Thanks a bunch anyways. :)